# PHP/PDO Data access layer query error: “Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch() on a non-object”

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am writing a web application to use CRUD (Create, Retrieve, Update and Delete) methods in a class to reduce code redundancy.  When I try to run the invoking code I keep getting a fatal error that my `$res` is a non-object. Why is my `$res` not being picked up as a valid object?

#### Invoking Code

```
$db = Database::getInstance($username, $password);
$exists = $db->tableExists($dbname, $tablename);

echo ($exists)? "TRUE" : "FALSE";
```

#### Database Class

```
class Database
{
    private static $instance;

    private $dbh;

    private static $dbengine = 'mysql';
    private static $dbname = 'database';
    private static $dbhost = 'localhost';


    function __construct($username, $password)
    {
        $dbname = Database::$dbname;
        $dbhost = Database::$dbhost;
        $dbengine = Database::$dbengine;
        $this->dbh =  new PDO("$dbengine:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
     }


    public static function getInstance($username, $password)
    {
        if (!isset(self::$instance))
        {
            $object = __CLASS__;
            self::$instance = new $object($username, $password);
        }
        return self::$instance;
    }


    public function tableExists($table)
    {
        $dbname = self::$dbname;
        $sql = $this->dbh->prepare("SHOW TABLES FROM :dbname like :table");
        $sql->bindParam(':dbname' , $dbname);
        $sql->bindParam( ':table', $table);
        $res = $sql->execute();
        $rows = $res->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
        if ($rows)
        {
            if ($rows[0] == 1)
            {
                return TRUE;
            }
            return FALSE;
        }
        return FALSE;
    }
```

}

#### Code Modified from the Following Link

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/real-world-oop-with-php-and-mysql--net-1918

When I run the Invoking Code I get:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch() on a non-object

Comment: @JakeGould, thank you for the title edit!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can PHP PDO Statements accept the table or column name as parameter?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/182287/can-php-pdo-statements-accept-the-table-or-column-name-as-parameter)

Comment: Your query is failing as you can't bind table names -> `SHOW TABLES FROM :dbname like :table`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My invoking code was incorrectly using two params.

```
$db->tableExists($dbname, $tablename);
```

So when I resolved it by removing the first parameter it worked.

```
$db->tableExists($tablename);
```

My query expected tablename is the first parameter but it saw **$dbname** which was causing my **tableExists** method to see the **$dbname** instead of **$tablename**.  Because of this my query was incorrectly resolving to

```
show tables from $dbname like '$dbname'
```

Answer (score 1):

Your error is this:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch() on a non-object

That kind of error pops up when you have no connection to the MySQL database or the query flat out fails. Your `$res` is a “non object” since there are no results.

A [quick Google search](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=CRUD%20Prigramming&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8#q=Fatal%20error:%20Call%20to%20a%20member%20function%20fetch()%20on%20a%20non-object) shows tons of results, but all slightly different solutions since everyone’s code is slightly different. But in your case, let’s look at this chunk of code in the constructor:

```
function __construct($username, $password)
 {
     $dbname = Database::$dbname;
     $dbhost = Database::$dbhost;
     $dbengine = Database::$dbengine;
     $this->dbh =  new PDO("$dbengine:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
 }
```

My gut feeling is something in there is not correct or not being set correctly. I would suggest you debug this using [`try`/`catch`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php) logic to give you more specific errors like this instead:

```
function __construct($username, $password)
 {
     $dbname = Database::$dbname;
     $dbhost = Database::$dbhost;
     $dbengine = Database::$dbengine;
     try {
       $this->dbh = new PDO("$dbengine:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
     }
     catch (PDOException $e) {
       echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
     }
 }
```

I would also recommend setting your MySQL instance to display connection errors like this:

```
function __construct($username, $password)
 {
     $dbname = Database::$dbname;
     $dbhost = Database::$dbhost;
     $dbengine = Database::$dbengine;
     try {
       $this->dbh = new PDO("$dbengine:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
       $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
     }
     catch (PDOException $e) {
       echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
     }
 }
```

And past the initial connection, then in your `tableExists` function do something like this; I’m quickly inserting some `try`/`catch` in here as well which should work but feel free to adjust to suit your actual coding needs:

```
public function tableExists($table)
{
    $dbname = self::$dbname;
    try {
      $sql = $this->dbh->prepare("SHOW TABLES FROM :dbname like :table");
      $sql->bindParam(':dbname' , $dbname);
      $sql->bindParam( ':table', $table);
      $res = $sql->execute();
    }
    catch (PDOException $e) {
      echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br />\n";
     return FALSE;
    }
    $rows = $res->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
    if ($rows)
    {
        if ($rows[0] == 1)
        {
            return TRUE;
        }
        return FALSE;
    }
    return FALSE;
}
```

Comment: I started off with a basic try catch wrapper before the response, but it was set to catch general exception not PDOException.  I will try this approach now.

Comment: So are you saying that binding the database and table name in `SHOW TABLES FROM :dbname like :table` is valid? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/182287/can-php-pdo-statements-accept-the-table-or-column-name-as-parameter

Comment: @Sean, I changed my variable substitution method to replace the prepared syntax I had before.  I now use $this->dbh->query("SHOW TABLES FROM $dbname like '$table'");  Unfortunately the error is still showing up.

Answer (score 1):

[`PDOStatement::execute()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php) doesn't return a result set, it simply returns `TRUE` or `FALSE`. You should be calling [`fetch()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) on the *statement* object:

```
$sql->execute();
$rows = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
```

Of course, you should still be doing proper error handling, which I leave as an exercise for the reader.